# selenium2 - java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

when i'm using selenium rc i used waitForPageToLoad method but in WebDriver i'm unable to find method for wait. is there any way to achieve this? i know webDriver allows wait For page Load implicitly but it's not working for me. thanks in advance.

Comment: you should mark this question as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver shouldn't return until the page has loaded, but if this is not working for you e.g. your pages is using AJAX, then you could add your own wait code using `wait.until` from `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait`.

There's a full example at http://www.qaautomation.net/?p=263